# Summation inside a range

Tags: algorithms, summation

I was a bit bored so I decided to create a program with a function that takes three variables:

`Upper`, `Lower`, and `Target`.

What the function does from that is loops through each integer from the range lower->upper, and in that loop, it has yet another loop that does that same thing.

So for every increment of the first loop, it goes through every number in that range again.

So that gives me two new variables, let's call them `k` and `n`.

Then I have an IF-statement that checks if k+n=Target, if so, it adds it to an array.

(I hope you understood that part)

[Here](http://i.gyazo.com/c466a549ae0f29c8e533c7dfff7485c7.png) is an example run of the program.

`As you maybe have noticed the number of ways it can be done within that range is equal to the Target - 1.`

Can somebody explain to me why this is the case?

I am sorry if my explanation was bad, English isn't my main language.

Here is the code-snippet, in c#:

```
public static void additions(Int64 upper, Int64 lower, Int64 target)
    {
        for (Int64 i = lower; i <= upper; i++)
        {
            for (Int64 k = lower; k <= upper; k++)
            {
                if (i + k == target)
                    results.Add(i.ToString() + " " + k.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: It's a bit unclear what's happening. Can you explain the algorithm in more detail or link to your source code?

Comment: @RandomUser Added the code.

Comment: Notice that once you have chosen `target` and `i`, there is only one possible value for `k`, namely `target - i`; if this number is in the required range it contributes 1 solution, and otherwise 0.  So your nested loop is unnecessary; you could do the same computation with `for (i=lower; i<=upper; i++) { k = target - i; if (lower <= k && k <= upper) { results.Add(...) } }`